# Glitch effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been spending my time making this kind-of glitch effect using javascript.
The glitch effect works by cycling through the alphabet(`alpha or alphaCaps variable`) and stops at a certain letter(`text variable`),
Here's the code:

```js
const text = 'TheThingThatDoesntEndWellWillEndWell'
const alphaCaps = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
const alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
var output = "";
var progress = 0;

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date <
    milliseconds);
}

function glitch() {
  while (output != text) {
    var randomNums = Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)
    if (alpha[randomNums] == text[progress] || alphaCaps[randomNums] == text[progress]) {
      output += text[progress];
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = `${output}`
      progress++;
      sleep(25);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = `${output}${alpha[randomNums]}`
      sleep(25);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="text"></h1>
<button onclick="glitch()">Glitch Button</button>
```

The problem is that when i pressed the button it doesn't show the process of the cycling.
I tried to put on sleep function but it doesn't work.
Can y'all help me please...

**WARNING: CAN CRASH YOUR BROWSER, PROBABLY.**

Comment: The problem could be is that `output` is never same as `text`. So it is a endless loop.

Comment: Sleep does not work that way. Try something like [this](https://medium.com/dev-genius/how-to-make-javascript-sleep-or-wait-d95d33c99909)

Comment: @brandt.codes But it IS ending well. See my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need a sleep. It just hangs the browser

- Call the function until the string is done using requestAnimationFrame for a smoother update too as suggested by Jaromanda X (I used setTimeout initially due to your 25 millisecs)
- Use event listeners which is recommended over inline event handlers
- Test the length of the string instead of the string. Much faster

```js
const text = 'The Thing That Doesn\'t End Well Will End Well'
const alphaCaps = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ', "'"];

const alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ', "'"];
var output = "";
var progress = 0;
const len = text.length;


function glitch() {
  if (progress >= len) {
    return;
  }  
  var randomNums = Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)
  if (alpha[randomNums] == text[progress] || alphaCaps[randomNums] == text[progress]) {
    output += text[progress];
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = `${output}`
    progress++;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = `${output}${alpha[randomNums]}`
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(glitch);
}

// just to make it nicer
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click",function() {
    this.hidden=true;
    glitch();
  });
})
```

```html
<h1 id="text"></h1>
<button type="button" id="but">Glitch Button</button>
```

Comment: use `requestAnimationFrame` for *smoother* animation :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, that was in my initial comment to the question too, I have just not used that myself before and did not want to change the code too much from the original

Comment: it'd be just `requestAnimationFrame(glitch)` instead of `setTimeout(glitch,25)`